# Absolute path for error_page in nginx?

Tags: configuration, nginx, webserver, absolute-path, custom-error-pages

Is there a way I can set an absolute path for nginx error_pages? Not absolute as in `http://`, but absolute as in `/usr/var/nginx/errors/500.html`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Sure you can but in an indirect way:

```
error_page 500 /500.html;
location = /500.html {
       root   /usr/var/nginx/errors;
       allow all;
       internal;
}
```

see http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#error_page

Comment: @magu [official docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) says it works in `http` context too. What version of nginx you are using?